# Hide Sidebar In Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

In woocommerce shop page (archive-product.php) i have listed category instead of product-listing, which list parent category **(Shop page display:Show Category)**,so when i click in parent category im redirect to child-category **(Category display: Show sub Category)** listing page,lastly when click on child-category im redirect to product listing of child-category,so im trying hide side-bar in parent-category and child category but display side-bar on product listing.

i found that shop-page uses archive-product.php (parent category displaying page) but both child-category and product listing uses taxonomy-product_cat.php so i couldn't assign different template to for displaying product listing as taxonomy-product_cat.php allow us for using different template **(wc_get_template( 'archive-product.php' );)**

```
i try to disable side-bar by following code putting it in **archive-product.php**
$prod_categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', array(
    'parent' => 0,

));

if ($prod_categories) {
   do_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar' );
}
```

but doesn't work for child-category
may following image will give clear idea

[Parent Category Without Side-bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqew9.jpg)

[Child Catgory Wihtout Side-bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfBOs.jpg)

[Product Listing With Side-bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uvZY.jpg)

Comment: Solved By creating custom template.

Comment: Solved By creating custom template.
parent-category = parent-category.php (custom-template)
child-category = child-category.php(custom-template)
product-listing = woocommerce-template

Parent-template {
parent-category loop start
$cat-id = woocommerce category id

<a href="<?php echo id? $cat-id "></a>

parent-category loop ends

Child-template {
$parent_cat_id = $_GET["id"];// gets parent-category id from parent-template

Child-category loop start

'child-of' = $parent_cat_id ,

Child-category loop ends